# Contradiction in Variance and Standard deviation values in Octave

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, stochastic-processes

I am defining a Normal Distribution in Octave by using this command "***y = normpdf(x,0,2)***". The standard deviation is 2 and x is independent uniform variable values. When I calculate standard deviation from ***std(y)*** then I do not get answer 2. 
Why is that so ?

Comment: What is the distribution of x?

Comment: Can you add a full reproducible example, i.e., containing also code that generates x

Comment: @Juho : x = (-5:0.01:5);
y = normpdf(x);
std_y = std(y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

normpdf(X,0,2) returns the probability density function at all values of X (be it a scalar, vector, or matrix) of a Normal random variable having mean = 0 and standard deviation = 2.

It does not return sample (simulated) values of such a Normal random variable. For that, either

A) use normrnd

or

B) generate uniform random variables and use them as arguments for the inverse Normal cdf.

So here is what I think you wanted to do:

```
>> % Method A
>> % Generates 1e6 Normal random numbers with mean 0, standard deviation 2
>> y = normrnd(0,2,1e6,1); 
>> disp(std(y))
    1.9994
```

or

```
>> % Method B
>> % Generate 1e6 U[0,1} r.v.s, apply inverse normal CDF, and multiply by standard deviation
>> u = rand(1e6,1);
>> y = 2*norminv(u);
>> disp(std(y))
    1.9991
```

Edit: Here is a plot of what you generated, which of course is the pdf:

```
>> x=-5:.01:5;
>> plot(x,normpdf(x,0,2))
```

[image]